# Mod (%) operator gives different output in C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Code-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int m=1000000007;
unsigned long int p=1,n,x[10]={40,50,60,98,106,114,122,130,138,146};

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{ 
  p=(p*x[i])%m;
  cout<<p<<"\n";} 

}
return 0; 
}
```

Output in visual studio-

```
40
2000
120000
11760000
246559993
338035412
585614586
115452127
47491617
638808772
```

Output on online IDE-

```
40
2000
120000
11760000
246559993
107839006
156358641
326623190
73999905
803986060
```

I'm executing my code in visual studio 2019. Why this modulo(%) operator is not working ( giving different answers)?

Comment: `unsigned long` is 32 bits on WIN64, and 64 bits on most other [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: ok, thank you. what can be used as a substitute to it?

Comment: to guarantee *at least* 64 bit values, use `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I'd use the standard integer typedefs from `<cstdint>` to make things easier on yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/5j6o6T - you can use `uint64_t` in your case.

Comment: ok, I'll try that too.

Comment: @BasGroothedde -- `uint64_t` is not required to exist; the platform might not have a 64-bit unsigned type. In cases like this, where the requirement is for a type that's **at least** a certain width, use `uint_least64_t` or `uint_fast64_t`. Those always exists.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/codingcompetitions/hacker-cup/2020/round-1/problems/A1

Comment: @BrettHale my boss insists we use `long` instead of `int` even though they're the same thing in Visual C++.  That's because he remembers a time when `int` was 16 bits, even though it hasn't been for at least 20 years.  It's thinking like that that keeps Microsoft mired in the past.

Comment: @PeteBecker agreed, however I figured from the code in the question that Tulsi required exactly 64-bits on a platform with `uint64_t` available, especially judging by them not expecting the integer truncation in different environments where these types are available.

Comment: @MarkRansom - that's... kind of correct though. An `int` is at least 16 bits in portable code. Assuming `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` is not portable. Even if the WIN64 LLP64 data model deviates from most typical Un*x LP64 models - it is still a conforming C implementation.

Comment: @BrettHale of course it's conforming, I never said it wasn't.  But the Windows application I work on would be in big trouble if Microsoft decided next year that `long` would be 64 bits, all because my boss is worried about something that hasn't been a problem in over 20 years and will never be a problem again.  The chances that Microsoft would decide to make `int` 16 bits is zero, even if it would still be conforming.

Comment: @MarkRansom - my point was, you should never have been using `int` as a 32-bit type to begin with. You're not going to reach an agreement with me on this issue. If I worked exclusively on win64, it might irritate me as well - but I have very little interest in that platform. I didn't mean to infer you weren't aware of the C requirements.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019), the data range of `unsigned long int` and `unsigned long long` is:

[image]

Also, `unsigned long int` is 4B under 32-bit and 8B under 64-bit. So, you could use `unsigned long long` rather than `unsigned long int`.